# Android - create shadow drawable programmatically

Tags: android, gradient, shadow

This is a gradient rectangle with rounded corners. The corner radious is 5dp and gray turns to completely transparent within 20dp.

How would I make this bitmap programmatically?

( It's important to have the corners do the same gradient color transition circularly. So I cannot use one rectangle gradient overlapping with an oval gradient coz this would create a darker area where the two gradients would overlap )

[image]

Comment: see `android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter`

Comment: but the real problem is with the implementation, since it is not clear if you need a `Drawable` (*create shadow drawable programmaticaly*) or `Bitmap` (*How would I make this bitmap programmaticaly?*)

Comment: either one is fine...One can be converted to the other so it doesn't matter.

Comment: so `Bitmap` is easier in use, but it will take more memory (could be important if it is full screen Bitmap